# Can I lock my notes with my OS X device?

Tags: macos, notes.app

With the most recent iOS update, Apple gave users the power to lock notes on their iOS device. Is this feature also available on OS X after the 10.11.4 update, and, if so, how do I use it? Or do I need to use my iOS device to lock my Notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a padlock icon on the toolbar of the Notes.app. You lock your note by clicking on it.

[image]

Comment: As a follow up to this question, does anyone know where the OS X Notes app stores locked notes on the file system? I looked around and couldn't find anything (I particularly looked in ~/Library and found a lot of directories and sub directories related to Notes, but was unsuccessful in finding the actual files or database which stores locked Notes). I'm curious because it might be worth writing a special launched item which monitors a folder (directory) on OS X for any changes to locked Notes as an additional security measure to be alerted to possible tampering with locked Notes on OS X.

Comment: @user3051849 if you have iCloud enabled on Notes everything is stored in DataBase here: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/CloudKit/Records/Records.db`.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek thank you, this is useful to know. I haven't yet synced Notes via iCloud but am thinking about it. Does Apple publicly state yet what type of encryption is used to protect the confidentiality of Notes? Also, if you lock a note using OS X (at least 10.11.4) and the note is synced with iCloud, can you unlock it with Notes on iOS (running at least iOS 9.3) for a device synced to the same iCloud account? What if you want to use TouchID on the iOS device to lock or unlock a note with Notes, does it matter? A password is always required for locking Notes on iOS right?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek To add to your comment about where Notes are stored with iCloud, OS X 10.11.4 partially manages Notes stored "On My Mac" underneath: `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/CoreData/ExternalRecords/NotesV4/` Look for a subdir prefix which begins with an alphanumeric (hex?) character string like: `F369624D-3473-45A8-9F6D-0495502A8D10//ICNote/_records/` then look for another subdir such as `0/` where you'll find files such as `p1.notesexternalrecord` On my Mac these files are 0 bytes, so its unclear where the actual contents of Notes "On My Mac" are stored.